# A 404 is retrieved in case the page is refreshed in any path in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

The 404 is retrieved if the page is refreshed in any path the problem does not occur in localhost but occurs after the project is uploaded to the server

When I refresh the page, this happens:

[image: Sorry, this page doesn't exist. Please check the URL or go back a page. 404 Error. Page Not Found.]

Comment: They have deployment docs for various providers. Also, where are you hosting it.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

Comment: Please add your code.